# No message in incoming twilio body from webhook

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

In all the twilio docs and examples I've read, the incoming body from an incoming sms webhook has a "message" property, however all I am getting is a single, ugly string.

```
// incoming request
{
    "body":"ToCountry=US&ToState=CA&SmsMessageSid=SMa40a4ba8fec941e6636ebd82aabxxx&NumMedia=0&ToCity=LAYTONVILLE&FromZip=45251&SmsSid=SMa40a4ba8fec941e6636ebd82aab1a080&FromState=OH&SmsStatus=received&FromCity=CINCINNATI&Body=message4321&FromCountry=US&To=%2B17074140303&ToZip=95417&NumSegments=1&MessageSid=SMa40a4ba8fec941e6636ebd82aab1a080&AccountSid=ACb237933f0f845f5cbe9fcbe67d3b604e&From=%2B15135057457&ApiVersion=2010-04-01",
    ...
}
```

What I want is in this field `Body=message4321` but I have to parse a string to do so.

I feel like I'm doing something wrong. Why does it look like query params? I set up the webhook by going into my phone number, then under messaging having "A message comes in Webhook POST https://my-url"

Answer (score 1):

I guess twilio sends the form as type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Using qs npm package is cleanest way to parse.

`qs.parse(queryString).Body;`

Comment: This is exactly right. You can parse the body like that, or if you're using express, take a look at using `body-parser` to automatically parse incoming request bodies.